# Excerpt showing under title in admin columns

Tags: admin, excerpt, columns

I am developing a site for a client, but i am facing a weird issue that is excerpt by default shows under title in admin columns. This is happening for all post types including custom post types. I tried following.

1. Disabled all plugins
2. Disabled all my code

But still that issue exists, i am running out of options and clueless how this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Here is the screenshot of what i am facing.]

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

Atlast i found the issue, it was very silly mistake. It got nothing to do with plugin or theme or any code. It was one of the WordPress settings which i didn't realize. Following pic shows the option to switch between excerpt view and list view of posts in wordpress. I by mistake selected excerpt view and thought it was a bug.

[image]

Anyway thanks for taking a look in to the issue.

Comment: Hi Pieter, I checked with twentyfifteen theme and twentyfourteen theme, i see the issue exists. very weird.

Comment: Hi Pieter, Thanks for looking in to the issue. I found the issue. Please check for my update in orginal issue description.

Comment: Please post your update as an answer and accept your own answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Atlast i found the solution, it was very silly mistake. It got nothing to do with plugin or theme or any code. It was one of the WordPress settings which i didn't realize. Following pic shows the option to switch between excerpt view and list view of posts in wordpress. I by mistake selected excerpt view and thought it was a bug.

[image]

Thanks for Pieter Goosen and whoever took a look at this issue :)